# VS Code using C not outputing to "Output" Tab

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I've been tring to program on VS Code in C for quite a while now but i can't get the output to go in the correct spot
As you can see in this really short test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("This is a test \n");
}
```

,and the adjacent image, the output goes to the debug console and not the output tab, or even the terminal
Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iujLs.png

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: For me (1.64.0-insider) the output goes to the Terminal tab. Which build task are you using (clang or gcc or a custom one)? Do you have the extension installed? Check also that in the Terminal tab you have the right process selected (there should be a few on the right)

Comment: @user16217248 Just added the screenshot, sorry about that, i already had but didn't notice the link was hidden

Comment: @lordnoob I have cgg installed. I have the C extension installed and the terminal tab has a preset and neither of the other options has the output I'm looking for. I got the latest VS code version